# Algoliasearch-Rails : Index variations of a single record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I would like to index differents variations of the same record, just like explained in [this doc](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/distinct#distinct-for-grouping):

How should I do this with the Algoliasearch-Rails gem ? I can't find any doc or example about this.

More details:

I have a model Card which embeds_many Locations (Mongoid).
For each location of this card, I would like to add a new record in my Algolia index and then Group the result by Card's slug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not something you can do with the current (`1.x`) version of the `algoliasearch-rails` library: a model is bound to a single index through through a single `algoliasearch` block.

I would recommend going with the underlying [Ruby API client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-ruby) and implement the logic you need in the `after_save/destroy` callbacks of your model.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply !